# Script timed out before returning headers: index.php

Tags: php, mysql, magento, e-commerce

I'm getting this error on a magento installation in the server logs and the site is throwing a 500 internal server error.

I haven't changed anything that I think could cause this. Does anyone know where this error is coming from and what the fix is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is anything mentionned in the server logs? I am willing to bet you will find your true answer there.

500 is an internal fatal error, *usually permission related*, but other issues can also cause this, improperly configured vhosts, improperly configured .htaccess ... and many others. Check your server logs you should have more details on the error.

Comment: i get more 500's from borked mod rewrite statements, than anything to do with permission issues

Comment: In the servers I work on, any fatal php error will throw the 500 header.

Comment: Ah! Indeed, good point.  I get more apache configuration related errors myself, but that my friend could be due to the fact that we tweak things more than the average Joe, thus break more stuff at a lower level.

Comment: @Sam - Yes. The webserver is basically telling you it could not do it's job because php could not do it's job. In general, this error can only be resolved by fixes to the Web server software. It is not a client-side problem. It is up to the operators of the Web server site to locate and analyse the logs which should give further information about the error.

Answer (score 0):

What were you trying to do that caused this error to appear?  I get it from time to time when I do something labor intensive.  For example, I'm in the process of importing around 10k products into my Magento build and got this same error message.  In this particular instance, I'd be willing to be it has to do with either your Apache timeout setting or your PHP max_execution_time setting or a combination of both.  It could also possibly be your PHP max_input_time setting if your like me and trying to upload/parse a giant CSV file full of products.  Don't be discouraged either if you have to play with the numbers little bit to find the right combo to make things work.  I have to try 3-4 times to get mine to run successfully.

A couple posts that helped me out were [Script timed out before returning headers: php.fastcgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225932/script-timed-out-before-returning-headers-php-fastcgi) and http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/74021/#t213112.