# Script timed out before returning headers: php.fastcgi

Tags: php, performance, fastcgi

After about 90 seconds I see this error in my apache error log. I'm assusming I need to increase a setting in PHP but I'm not sure which one to change.

Is there one setting I can increase to clear this error?

Comment: As a general point, I would very must question the wisdom of doing any web request which takes anything like 90s to respond.  The end-user will probably get bored and exit the browser screen long before this timeout.  Such long requests are better optimised, moved to a batch Q or psuedo-batched using a Refresh HTTP header to force periodic repolling and progress update.

Comment: @TerryE What if the user is an administrator or employee of the company that runs the website? What if it is an expensive transaction performed by an employee of the company that runs the website? You are right, not acceptable to wait over 90 seconds, but think about other user types, not only regular visitors of the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find in your `php.ini` file something like this:

```
; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 600    

; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data. It's a good
; idea to limit this time on productions servers in order to eliminate unexpectedly
; long running scripts. 
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to -1 for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
; Development Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; Production Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; http://php.net/max-input-time
max_input_time = 600
```

Edit the values, restart apache and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `set_time_limit(0);` for an infinite time limit in your PHP script.